# how can I catch the deserialization error or xml from a dynamic soap-web-service?

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl

I am creating (successfully) a dynamic webservice via ServiceDescription and ServiceDescriptionImporter.

**BUT**

how the heck do I intercept the deserialization (error:InvalidCast... can not convert to array)
if I get some wrong xml-document from the web service host ?
even reading the wrong xml-document is a mistery for me.

Is it possible to replace the generated SoapHttpClientProtocol ?
Or the XmlSerializer ?

If so, **HOW** ?

I do not want to fail the whole request.

can someone help me out ?

Comment: So, receiving a wrong Xml is an error by any mean. Can you describe what do you mean by "semi-valid" xml? What kind of error do you want to handle and process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well finally I was able to **replace GetWebResponse** via IL-Emitter.

Hard stuff though... 
The closest hint I got was [here](http://rebuildall.umbraworks.net/2009/09/22/Overriding_virtual_methods_at_runtime)

If anyone is interessted, I can show more code. just drop a line.

*thanks for passing by.*